# Owl Carousel Plugin - Need to repeat carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I'm using the [Owl Carousel plugin version 2](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/) to add some carousels to my site.

This version of Owl Carousel allows users to extend it's functionality by creating add-on plugins. I'm using an add-on plugin I found to make the carousel display on 2 rows instead of one. This is illustrated in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BBoyJuss/thbLB/light/). I can get this working no problem.

The issue I have is that I want to create two of these carousels. When I create the second carousel though it doesn't work.

Here is the code for the add-on plugin:

```
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    Owl2row = function (scope) {
    this.owl = scope;
    this.owl.options = $.extend(Owl2row.Defaults, this.owl.options);
    //link callback events with owl carousel here

    this.handlers = {
        'initialize.owl.carousel': $.proxy(function (e) {
            if (this.owl.settings.owl2row) {
                this.build2row(this);
            }
        }, this)
    };

    this.owl.$element.on(this.handlers);
};

Owl2row.Defaults = {
    owl2row: 'true',
    owl2rowTarget: 'item',
    owl2rowContainer: 'owl2row-item',
    owl2rowDirection: 'utd' // ltr
};

//mehtods:
Owl2row.prototype.build2row = function(thisScope){

    var carousel = $('.' + thisScope.owl.options.baseClass);
    var carouselItems = carousel.find('.' + thisScope.owl.options.owl2rowTarget);

    var aEvenElements = [];
    var aOddElements = [];

    $.each(carouselItems, function (index, item) {
        if ( index % 2 === 0 ) {
            aEvenElements.push(item);
        } else {
            aOddElements.push(item);
        }
    });

    carousel.empty();

    switch (thisScope.owl.options.owl2rowDirection) {
        case 'ltr':
            thisScope.leftToright(thisScope, carousel, carouselItems);
            break;

        default :
            thisScope.upTodown(thisScope, aEvenElements, aOddElements, carousel);
    }

};

Owl2row.prototype.leftToright = function(thisScope, carousel, carouselItems){

    var o2wContainerClass = thisScope.owl.options.owl2rowContainer;
    var owlMargin = thisScope.owl.options.margin;

    var carouselItemsLength = carouselItems.length;

    var firsArr = [];
    var secondArr = [];

    //console.log(carouselItemsLength);

    if (carouselItemsLength %2 === 1) {
        carouselItemsLength = ((carouselItemsLength - 1)/2) + 1;
    } else {
        carouselItemsLength = carouselItemsLength/2;
    }

    //console.log(carouselItemsLength);

    $.each(carouselItems, function (index, item) {


        if (index < carouselItemsLength) {
            firsArr.push(item);
        } else {
            secondArr.push(item);
        }
    });

    $.each(firsArr, function (index, item) {
        var rowContainer = $('<div class="' + o2wContainerClass + '"/>');

        var firstRowElement = firsArr[index];
            firstRowElement.style.marginBottom = owlMargin + 'px';

        rowContainer
            .append(firstRowElement)
            .append(secondArr[index]);

        carousel.append(rowContainer);
    });

};

Owl2row.prototype.upTodown = function(thisScope, aEvenElements, aOddElements, carousel){

    var o2wContainerClass = thisScope.owl.options.owl2rowContainer;
    var owlMargin = thisScope.owl.options.margin;

    $.each(aEvenElements, function (index, item) {

        var rowContainer = $('<div class="' + o2wContainerClass + '"/>');
        var evenElement = aEvenElements[index];

        evenElement.style.marginBottom = owlMargin + 'px';

        rowContainer
            .append(evenElement)
            .append(aOddElements[index]);

        carousel.append(rowContainer);
    });
};

/**
 * Destroys the plugin.
 */
Owl2row.prototype.destroy = function() {
    var handler, property;

    for (handler in this.handlers) {
        this.owl.dom.$el.off(handler, this.handlers[handler]);
    }
    for (property in Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)) {
        typeof this[property] !== 'function' && (this[property] = null);
    }
};



 $.fn.owlCarousel.Constructor.Plugins['owl2row'] = Owl2row;
})( window.Zepto || window.jQuery, window,  document );
```

And here is the code I'm using to create the 2 carousels:

```
jQuery(function () {

    var owl = jQuery('#owl2row-plugin');
    owl.owlCarousel({
        loop: false,
        dots: false,
        margin: 10,
        nav: true,
        navText: ["<< Prev","Next >>"],
        owl2row: 'true', // enable plugin
        owl2rowTarget: 'item',    // class for items in carousel div
        owl2rowContainer: 'owl2row-item', // class for items container
        owl2rowDirection: 'utd', // ltr : directions
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1
            },
            600: {
                items: 2
            },
            1000: {
                items: 3
            }
        }
    });

     var owl2 = jQuery('#owl2row-plugin-2');
    owl2.owlCarousel({
        loop: false,
        dots: false,
        margin: 10,
        nav: true,
        navText: ["<< Prev","Next >>"],
        owl2row: 'true', // enable plugin
        owl2rowTarget: 'item',    // class for items in carousel div
        owl2rowContainer: 'owl2row-item-2', // class for items container
        owl2rowDirection: 'utd', // ltr : directions
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1
            },
            600: {
                items: 2
            },
            1000: {
                items: 3
            }
        }
    });


});
```

Assistance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want 2 rotators, each showing 2 rows? For a total of 4 rotating images?

Comment: 2 carousels yes, each with 2 rows. Each carousel though has many items. Basically I want whats shown in the JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/BBoyJuss/thbLB/light/ except repeated twice. I have it working already with one but activating 2 isn't working for me.